# M.2 (or NGFF) SSD cloning, how to clone to a M-key PCIe SSD using an external USB connection?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning, m.2, ngff

The usual way I do this is connect two drives to a computer using the USB interface and a cloning software like FarStone. Afterwards I would install the new cloned drive in the laptop/computer. I have found that the fastest and easiest way to make reliable 1 to 1 clones.

Enter M.2 or NGFF SSDs. I did not know there were so many factors to consider here. Is it M Key, or B+M key, is it Sata or PCIe. I'm not even sure I know all the combinations. Being very computer familiar this has actually caught me off guard and I fear I will make the wrong purchases going forward.

I need to clone from a B+M SSD (sata) to a M Key PCIe SSD drive. 
I have one B or B+M SSD to USB 3.0 adaptor which works fine with the first drive but I am not sure I can find a PCIe SSD adaptor for my M key SSD in the market that either gives me a USB 3.0 or Sata connector that I could connect to a computer externally.

Any help would be appreciated, what adaptor do I need for my second SSD drive? Examples, Amazon/eBay links would be appreciated. 
[This is the model if it helps](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/256gb-samsung-sm951-m2-(22x80)-pcie-30-(x4)-ahci-ssd-mlc-nand-read-2150mb-s-write-1200mb-s-90k-70k-i).

[image]

Comment: [Distinguishing the AHCI and NVMe version from each other isn't very simple as the difference lies in a single character in the model number. The AHCI version carries the code MZ-HPVxxx0 (where xxx is the capacity in gigabytes), whereas the NVMe version is called MZ-VPVxxx0.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9396/samsung-sm951-nvme-256gb-pcie-ssd-review)

Comment: I am not aware that there are any NVMe to USB adapter so far, and AFAIK, you can't use the SATA to USB one for NVMe drives since they do not speak ATA commands. However, if you've provided the correct information, your drive seems to be of the SATA variant of the series. But I've only seen enclosure for B-key drives on StarTech, not any for M-key ones.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/M2_Edge_Connector_Keying.svg/400px-M2_Edge_Connector_Keying.svg.png

Comment: @Tom To reply to your second comment, in the specs it says, PCIe 3.0. Also SATA can not achieve these speeds yet. 

So are you saying there are no PCIe M.2 connectors to USB at the moment?

Comment: @Mohammad Could you find a PCIe M.2 M-Key to USB Adapter? I have the same drive as above recovered from a broken Surface Pro 4...

Comment: @user797717 No the adaptor was not found, I had to insert it in a computer and use bootable windows installation to manually instal everything unfortunately. Another way to accomplish this is to use a laptop with multiple M.2 ports, like some of the Dell Alienwares.

Comment: I think you can't connect a M.2 M-key to SATA3 - I've read where it isn't fast enough, which explains why they can't be found on amazon. http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3084504/ssds-key-sata-adapter-needed.html

Comment: Neither can I find any adapter for the M-key chip.  I've looked all over and cannot learn even how to put it in my computer to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using dd(a linux command).

Since you have M.2 SSD and you are trying to use it, I assume one of your system should support those devices.

Just insert the two devices into the slot, boot the computer but do not boot from either of the two devices you want to manipulate. One of the option is that you can boot the computer from an Ubuntu live cd(or USB).

Let's take Ubuntu live cd as an example. When system boots up:

1. open an terminal(not root permission)
2. `sudo gnome-terminal &`
   open a root permission terminal and detach it from the 1st terminal by cmd
3. `lsblk`.
   Use this command to find your devices. Let's say your source device is sdx, and the target device is sdy
4. `dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy bs=4k`
   This command copies the content from sdx to sdy. The parameter "bs=4k" is not necessarily needed but most of the time it makes the copy speed faster even for SSD. Believe me I was a bit of expert on this.
5. `watch -n 5 killall -USR1 dd`
   During the copying process, you many wonder if everything OK? Because the dd command yield no message during the copy process. Fortunately you can open another root terminal and send USR1 signal. The dd process will print some information on the screen.

Or if you are looking for a productive tool, you may consider this PCIe duplicator
http://phiyo.en.alibaba.com/product/60343552337-212597355/PE_1051_PCIe_Duplicator_.html#!

Answer (score 0):

What if you could find an external M.2 enclosure with some interface your computer could use?  Say you had an external 3.5" SATA drive bay, or even one of those USB to SADA adapters.

Then, maybe you could use something like this:
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1264951-REG/asus_hyper_express.html

or, if you have a USB interface and some money: 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-USB-3-0-to-M-2-M-Key-PCI-Express-SSD-Mobile-hard-disk-box/32787181713.html